# Advice about modify compiler to add extra bytes for each function

Tags: c++, c, compilation

Ftrace supports dynamic trace, that is, it can trace any global function in the kernel and modules. It uses the -pg compilation option of gcc to add a stub at the beginning of each function, so that when needed, the function can be controlled to jump to the specified code for execution. gcc 4.6 newly added -pg -mfentry support, so that an instruction to call fentry can be inserted at the very beginning of the function, like:

[root@localhost kernel-4.4.27]# echo 'void foo(){}' | gcc -x c -S -o - - -pg -mfentry

foo:
.LFB0:

```
.cfi_startproc
call    __fentry__
pushq   %rbp
.cfi_def_cfa_offset 16
.cfi_offset 6, -16
movq    %rsp, %rbp
.cfi_def_cfa_register 6
popq    %rbp
.cfi_def_cfa 7, 8
ret
.cfi_endproc
```

What I need to do is like -pg option, however I wanna leave 5 extra bytes both at the begin and the end of each function to modify for my use, so I need some advice about how to modify clang or llvm to realize it (because gcc maybe too hard for me to understand and modify)

Comment: "advice on how to modify clang or LLVM" is *way* out of scope for an SO question. Since -pg -mfentry already does half of what you need, why not source-dive for the code behind those options?

Comment: Maybe, a stupid workaround: Use gcc to emit assembly code instead of `.o` files. (You already did.) Then this might degrade to a "simple" text copy-paste task. Finally, compile the modified assembly. No need to modify every involved tool - at most one to add in your tool chain in case. (I must admit that it's over 20 years ago that I touched assembly code myself.) ;-)

Comment: Not sure, but, maybe, you can (ab)use `-finstrument-functions` (found in [gcc doc. - Program Instrumentation Options](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc-11.2.0/gcc/Instrumentation-Options.html#Instrumentation-Options).)